# TFS API for team capacity work details

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

I'd like to retrieve the team capacity work details (the right area of the team capacity web page) using the TFS REST API.

Can this be achieved?
I tried to use the "[Get a team's capacity](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/work/capacity#get-a-teams-capacity)" API but it returns only the days off and the capacity per day for the team members.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are meaning the work details such as below picture

[image]

There is no REST API or Client API will directly return such things. If you have got remaining work days. According to the returned team members days off and capacity per day. You should be able to  calculate the values.